# Playing the sent email swoosh sound

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, audio

I would like to close a view controller and get a swoosh sound similar to sending an email.  Any idea how I could approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the [System Sound](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference) or the [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Classes for your sound. The [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class has a `viewWillDisappear:` and a `viewDidDisappear:`. You can insert your code there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Audio Toolbox:

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Load your audio resource like this:

```
NSURL* soundUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"emailsent" withExtension: @"aif"];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)(soundUrl), &emailSentSoundId);
```

Where emailSentSoundId should be declared as:

```
SystemSoundID emailSentSoundId;
```

Play the sound like this:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(emailSentSoundId);
```